# how make double paste in each rows on excel?

Tags: database, excel, formula, rows

i have record **30.942** row, in my case example : 
234
543
222
456
674
what should i do want to this :
234
234
543
543
222
222
456
456
674
674

PLEASE how to make double every row??

Answer (score 1):

Create two other columns (C and D in the image below) and enter formula as shown. Should give you the desired result. Update the ranges to suit your data.

[image: Double Row]

If you want to do it by VBA, then use the below code.

A1:A23 is the data range. Result is printed in column E. Make sure its empty.

```
Sub doubleRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim counter As Integer
    counter = 0

    For Each c In Range("A1:A23")
        Range("E1").Offset(counter, 0) = c
        Range("E1").Offset(counter + 1, 0) = c
        counter = counter + 2
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot. But i found new simple way with vlookup and gift $ to read variable column. Thanks stack overflow it first experience i ask in here.